# Getting data by form and pass to controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to take an id as input by the user and pass to the controller to get the data of particular id

it's working when I pass id manually in URL --  http://localhost:8080/student/1

```
<form th:action="@{{student}/{id}}" th:object="${Student}" method="post">
                    Roll Number:<br>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{id}"><br>
                    <br><br>
                    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

```
@GetMapping(value = "/student/{id}")
    public Optional<Student> getStudentDetail(@PathVariable int id){
        return studentRepository.findById(id) ;
    }
```

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jun 19 11:04:22 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/student.html]")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change as **AmirBll** said, ***Also***, you have to change your controller `HTTP` method from `@GetMapping(value = "/student/{id}")` to `@PostMapping(value = "/student/{id}")` as `form data` submission is `POST` method you declared in the form.

Answer (score 1):

In the form attribute you have used method="post" while in the controller class you are using @GetMapping. Use this

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{id}">
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" th:="*{id}"><br>
```

Also make getter / setter of id attributes in the Student class

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'Student' available as request attribute

Comment: try with th:object="${student}" instead of th:object="${Student}". Also the Student class must be under package which used in @ComponnetScan

Comment: can you please confirm that Student form bean is being loaded in the application context

Comment: No, it is not loaded in the application context

Comment: load this Form Bean class in the applicationContext, looks like the issue related to the non-availability of bean

Answer (score 0):

you should use `th:field` for `<input>`:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{id}">
```

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jun 19 11:27:55 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "student" - line 16, col 40)

Comment: by using <input type="text" th:field="*{id}">